# OpenCL remote debugging

Tags: opencl

I am writing opencl code on an amazon instance. Can someone please tell me how I could debug my code remotely. I tried gDEbugger from the AMD website, but it requires an X server running.

Comment: What's the OpenCL device that you're targeting?

Comment: It is an Nvidia Grid K520

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are currently no debugging tools available for OpenCL running on NVIDIA GPUs. Although NVIDIA have some tools for debugging CUDA applications, none of these are compatible with OpenCL yet. All you can do on NVIDIA devices is copy data back to the host and inspect it there.

If you have access to alternative OpenCL implementations your best bet is to run your code on these instead and use the available debugging tools. For AMD GPUs, there is [CodeXL](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/codexl/), which should provide fairly sophisticated OpenCL kernel debugging capabilities. On CPUs, you can use GDB/Visual Studio. On all these devices, you also have `printf` available from within kernels (primitive, but still very useful).

There are other third-party tools that can help identify certain problems. For example, [GPUVerify](http://multicore.doc.ic.ac.uk/tools/GPUVerify/) can help identify data-races inside kernels. [Oclgrind](https://github.com/jrprice/Oclgrind/wiki) runs OpenCL applications in a simulated environment to catch memory access errors, data-races and more, and provides an interactive GDB-style debugger to step through kernel source. As the OpenCL ecosystem continues to expand, I'd expect to see more of these third-party tools start to appear.

Comment: I see. Can I use AMD's OpenCL if I have an Nvidia card? Will CodeXL work from the command line?

Comment: No, CodeXL will only work on AMD GPUs. The latest CodeXL does have some support for generate profiling data via the command-line, intended for headless servers. There's also a remote debugging capability, which allows you to run CodeXL on a local machine and connect to a remote client.

Comment: One more thing: in my experience, using a printf within a kernel works only if the printf is not inside a loop. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: No, there should be no such restrictions against using `printf` like that. Sounds like a bug in the OpenCL implementation to me.

Comment: Okay, so I tried to install oclgrind on my machine. In the tools directory off llvm, I cloned the repository at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIR. The comment below shows the error I got.

Comment: llvm[3]: Compiling ClangAttrEmitter.cpp for Release+Asserts build
ClangAttrEmitter.cpp: In function ‘void writePrettyPrintFunction(llvm::Record&, std::vector<{anonymous}::Argument*>&, llvm::raw_ostream&)’:
ClangAttrEmitter.cpp:943:22: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘const char [17]’ and ‘llvm::StringRef’)
       "    OS << \"" + Prefix.str() + Spelling.str();
                      ^
ClangAttrEmitter.cpp:957:24: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘llvm::StringRef’ and ‘const char [4]’)
     OS << Suffix.str() + "\";\n";
                        ^

Comment: @user1274878 Looks like you haven't checked out the SPIR branch. Did you run `git checkout -t origin/spir_12` from `tools/clang`? You also need to checkout the 3.2 branch of LLVM (`git checkout -t origin/release_32` from the LLVM source root).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62351/discussion-between-user1274878-and-jprice).